# Get sum of difference of rows in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with given values

```
| id  | level  | value |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 30000  | 0.05  |
| 2   | 100000 | 0.06  |
| 3   | 120000 | 0.07  |
```

I want to create an postgres sql query to get a sum in the following logic. I will be providing a value (level) as as parameter to the query (170000).

`(100000- 30000)*0.05 + (120000-100000)*0.06 + (170000-120000)*0.07`

(difference of level of row2  and row1) * value of row1 +
(difference of level of row3  and row2) * value of row2 +
(difference of level as input  and row3) * value of row3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEAD` to see the next row's value. Use `COALESCE` to substitute the last missing value with 170000.

```
select sum(subtotal) as total
from
(
  select
    (coalesce(lead(level) over (order by id), 170000) - level) * value as subtotal
  from mytable
) subtotals;
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `LEAD` function to get the next level value, and find the sum according to your logic as the following:

```
SELECT SUM((nextLevel-level)*value) AS res
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    LEAD(LEVEL, 1, 170000) OVER (ORDER BY id) nextLevel
  FROM tbl
) T
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/r6jIq3eU).

Comment: Oh yes, I completely forgot that `LEAD` allows us to provide a default value. This makes this very readable.